# Plotting using RandomReal output

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, random

```
jj=RandomReal[{-1,1},1000];

a=c;  (* c is any constant *)

For[k=1,k<=1000,k++,
y={{a^2*jj[k],a*jj[k]},{a*jj[k],(a^3+4)*jj[k]}};
   ];

x1=Sort[y[[1,1]]]; x2=Sort[y[[2,2]]];

p1=ListLinePlot[{x1,x2}]
```

I want to plot x1 vs. x2. I know they can be computed even without using a matrix as here but I would like to know how elements of a matrix can be manipulated either for calculations or for plotting.
I would like to thank you in advance.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do *in plain words*, in such a way that it is understandable without any code.

Comment: You do realize that the first line is irrelevant since `j` is overridden immediately in the `For` loop? Also, the loop just overrides `y`over and over. And finally, the `Table` statement in the last line also does nothing interesting, since nothing depends on `j`. (look at `x1`/`x2`)

Comment: @Mathe172 In the first line I am generating 1000 random numbers which are used in the `For` loop.You are right about `Table` as I mentioned.

Comment: perhaps `For[n = 1, n <= 1000, n++, 
  y = {{a^2*j[[n]], a*j[[n]]}, {a*j[[n]], (a^3 + 4)*j[[n]]}};];`

Comment: "1000 random numbers which are used in the `For` loop" - no, they are not. In the loop, `j` is an iterator that goes from 1 to 1000. Period. Your random numbers, as defined in the first line, are `j[[1]]` as the first element, `j[[2]]` as the second, ..., `j[[i]]` as the *i*th. Maybe you want something like: `For[i=1,i<=1000,i++,
y={{a^2*j[[i]],a*j[[i]]},{a*j[[i]],(a^3+4)*j[[i]]}};
   ]`? But note that `y` is just `{{0.0867359 a^2, 0.0867359 a}, {0.0867359 a, 0.0867359 (4 + a^3)}}`... If you want a list of such `y`s applied to each random number `j[[i]]`, just do: (....)

Comment: (....) `Table[{{a^2 j[[i]], a j[[i]]}, {a j[[i]], (a^3 + 4) j[[i]]}}, {i, 1, 
  1000}]` or simply `{{a^2 #, a #}, {a #, (a^3 + 4) #}} & /@ j`. See also [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Comment: @corey979 Now, I edited my question, please have a look. This is a simple example code I have written. I need these techniques in much bigger context.

Comment: @user31694 Did you read through the answer in the linked post? There's still no reason to use `For` in your example, even `jj*{{a^2,a},{a,a^3+4}}` would work here since every element is simply multiplied by `jj[k]`. And to repeat: You just assign a new value to `y` in every iteration of the loop in your current code

Comment: @Mathe172 It is true for this particular example but I have a much general problem at hand which needs such multiplication inside a matrix.

Comment: I voted to close this question as unclear because you refused to explain the problem in simple words, and people are clearly wasting their time by *trying to guess*. The code has so many problems that it is impossible to tell what you are trying to do.  Remember that even if the question gets closed, it can be re-opened *after it has been edited and the problem has been explained in a clear manner*.

Comment: All you need to do is explain your problem in words (so it can be understood even without reference to any code). Why do you keep changing the code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, as your actual goal is a little opaque.

To figure things out, start with a smaller list:

```
SeedRandom[1];
jj = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
```

Notice that

```
Clear[a]
a^2 jj

(* {0.634779 a^2, -0.777161 a^2, 0.579052 a^2, -0.624394 a^2, -0.517278 a^2,   
   -0.868522 a^2, 0.0844932 a^2, -0.537691 a^2, -0.207988 a^2, 0.400948 a^2} *)
```

That is, if you want to multiply a list by a number, you can just multiply a list by a number. So, perhaps you want:

```
y1 = Transpose[{a^2 jj, a jj}];
y2 = Transpose[{a jj, (a^3 + 4) jj}];

(* y1 = {{0.634779 a^2, 0.634779 a}, {-0.777161 a^2, -0.777161 a}, {0.579052 a^2, 0.579052 a}, 
         {-0.624394 a^2, -0.624394 a}, {-0.517278 a^2, -0.517278 a}, {-0.868522 a^2, -0.868522 a}, 
         {0.0844932 a^2, 0.0844932 a}, {-0.537691 a^2, -0.537691 a}, {-0.207988 a^2, -0.207988 a}, 
         {0.400948 a^2, 0.400948 a}} *)
```

So `y1` and `y2` are lists of pairs generated from your random numbers by the specified formulae.

I will assume you want to plot these points for some value of `a`:

```
ListPlot[{y1, y2} /. a -> 0.5]
```

[image]

There are more concise ways of doing this, if you so wish. I would strongly encourage you to thoroughly read the documentation of any interesting looking functions and play with the examples therein. Most things are probably much easier than you think they'll be.